# MariaDB SQL in Node throwing ER_PARSE_ERROR when I try to query an array of data

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mariadb

I'm trying to feed an Array of data formatted like this

```
[ 3717003570,'HYDRAULIC ACTUATOR','DIAMEC','EXPLORATION',2,16071.59]
```

and its returning the error saying

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '3717003570, 'HYDRAULIC ACTUATOR', 'DIAMEC',
>   'EXPLORATION', 2, 16071.59' at line 1

While when I try to manually insert the data with a query in SequelPro it isn't throwing any sort of error

EDIT: Whole statement

```
    var query = "INSERT INTO products (ITEMNO, DESCRIPTION, MODEL, CATEGORY, QTY, PRICE) VALUES ?";
con.query(query, values, (err, results)=> {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Sucess, Rows Affected:" + results.affectedRows);
})
```

Comment: Please show us the whole statement.

Comment: Added the code that calls the query into the post

Comment: Let's see what `values` contains.  Smells like it is an array, yet, the syntax is asking for a string.

Comment: Values does contain an array from a JSON file, as far as I can tell this is the proper way to pass it to the Query

Comment: But `INSERT` is expecting a single value for the `?`, not an array.